# Is it possible to retrieve text files from HTML app directory without HTTP request or <input>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, src

I'm working on an HTML/javascript app intended to be run locally.

When dealing with img tags, it is possible to set the src attribute to a file name with a relative path and thereby quickly and easily load an image from the app's directory. I would like to use a similar method to **retrieve a text file from the *app's directory***.

I have used TideSDK, but it is less lightweight. And I am aware of HTTP requests, but if I remember correctly only Firefox has taken kindly to my use of this for local file access (although accessing local images with src does not appear to be an issue). I am also aware of the FileReader object; however, my interface requires that I load a file **based on the file name** and **not based on a file-browser selection** as with `<input type="file">`.

Is there some way of accomplishing this type of file access, or am I stuck with the methods mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will not permit you to access files like that but you can make javascript files instead of text files like this:

text1.js:

```
document.write('This is the text I want to show in here.');   //this is the content of the javascript file
```

Now call it anywhere you like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="text1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too many security issues (restrictions) within browsers making many local web-apps impossible to implement so my solution to a similar problem was to move out of browsers and into node-webkit which combines Chromium + Node.js + your scripts, into an executable with full disk I/O.

http://nwjs.io/

Answer (score 0):

[edit] I'm sorry I thought you wanted to do this with TideSDK, I'll let my answer in case you want to give another try to TideSDK [/edit]

I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for but I will try to explain my case.
I've an application which allow the user to save the state of his progress. To do this, I allow him to select a folder, enter a filename and write this file. When the user open the app, he can open the saved file, and get back his progress. So I assume this enhancement is similar of what you are looking for.

In my case, I use the native File Select to allow the user to select a specific save (I'm using CoffeeScript) :

```
Ti.UI.currentWindow.openFileChooserDialog(_fileSelected, {
  title: 'Select a file'
  path: Ti.Filesystem.getDocumentsDirectory().nativePath()
  multiple: false
})
```

(related doc http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.UI.UserWindow-method-openFileChooserDialog)

When this step is done I will open the selected file :

```
if !filePath?
  fileToLoad = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(scope.fileSelected.nativePath())
else
  fileToLoad = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(filePath)
data = Ti.JSON.parse(fileToLoad.read())
```

(related doc http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Filesystem)

Please note that those snippets are copy/paste from my project and they will not work without the rest of my code but I think it's enough to illustrate you how I manage to open a file, and read his content.

In this case I'm using Ti.JSON.parse because there is only javascript object in these files but in your case you can just get the content. The openFileChooserDialog isn't mandatory, if you already know the file name, or if you get it from another way you can use Ti.Filesystem in your own way.